# Knockout foreach index based on visible/existing elements

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

I have data that is given as JSON and mapped to KO observable, the data is structured like this:

```
list : [
    {
        ItemNumber: 1,
        ItemPhotos: null
    },
    {
        ItemNumber: 2,
        ItemPhotos: ["Photo1Url", Photo2Url, Photo3Url...]
    },  
    {
        ItemNumber: 3,
        ItemPhotos: ["Photo1Url", Photo2Url,...]
    },     
    ...
]
```

Then in my codefront I want to display all of the ItemPhotos so I loop through like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
    <!-- ko if: ItemPhotos -->
        <!-- ko foreach: ItemPhotos -->
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data}"/>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Now this works fine and just shows all images. However, I want to limit it to only show the first 5 images (total, not per item). I also want to style the first image (again first out of all of them, not first in each array.

So what I thought would work would just be checking the $index, but if I put the index inside the "ItemPhotos" foreach then it would style the first photo for each item and only up to 5 photos per item (for unlimited items). If I checked the index in the "list" foreach I would style the all of the first items photos and allow only 5 items regardless of how many photos they have. This is more difficult with the fact that some items can have no photos.

Is there anyway to do these checks in my binding *without* changing my data structure, as I use the data in this structure further down the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to limit it to only show the first 5 images (total, not per item)"?

Comment: @haim770 Suppose there was 10 items in my array of objects up there and each item had 10 photos. I would want the first 5 images from the first item and be done (because that is 5 total), not 5 images from each of the 10 items.

Comment: That's going to be a pretty ugly binding. It would definitely be better to restructure or add to your viewmodel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do data manipulation in your viewmodel, not in your view. A computed can give you what you want.

```js
const vm = {
  list: ko.observableArray([{
      ItemNumber: 1,
      ItemPhotos: null
    },
    {
      ItemNumber: 2,
      ItemPhotos: ["2Photo1Url", '2Photo2Url', '2Photo3Url']
    },
    {
      ItemNumber: 3,
      ItemPhotos: ["3Photo1Url", '3Photo2Url']
    },
    {
      ItemNumber: 4,
      ItemPhotos: ["4Photo1Url", '4Photo2Url']
    }
  ])
};

vm.firstFive = ko.computed(() => {
  const result = vm.list().reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b.ItemPhotos || []), []).slice(0,5);

  console.log(result);
  return result;
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: firstFive">
  <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data}" />
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You accumulated all images to a single list then keep returning the first 5 regardless of the item being iterated. That's not what the OP wants

Comment: That's how I read "the first five, total". How do you read it?

Comment: Why is there confusion? "Suppose there were 10 items in my array of objects and each item had 10 photos. I would want the first 5 images from the first item and be done, not 5 images from each of the 10 items."

Comment: Also he doesn't say he needs anything else about the "items" except the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a `GetItemPhotos()` method that will return an empty array upon reaching your limit:

```
var photosCounter = 0,
    maxPhotosToReturn = 5;

yourViewModel.GetItemPhotosFor = function(item) {
    if (!item.ItemPhotos || photosCounter >= maxPhotosToReturn) return [];

    var photos = item.ItemPhotos.slice(0, maxPhotosToReturn - photosCounter);
    photosCounter += photos.length;

    return photos;
};
```

And in your HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.GetItemPhotosFor($data) -->
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data }"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```